# How do I solve "E: Unable to locate package kali-linux-top10" in kali linux?

Tags: kali-linux

I can install gimp, vlc but when I try to run *sudo apt-get install kali-linux-top10* or *sudo apt-get install kali-linux-all* I get this error.

I've tried typing following lines in **/etc/apt/source.list** from https://www.kali.org/docs/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories/

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib

deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib

deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-last-snapshot main non-free contrib

deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-experimental main non-free contrib

deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
```

Now my ***source.list*** looks like this

[image]

And the output in terminal looks like this

[image]

Comment: All I've heard about kali is that it's a very bad choice for your main distro, the existence of any of those packages (judging from their names) would just increase that impression.

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).  Copy and paste the text itself **into your question** and format it as code by selecting it and pressing Ctrl-K or by using the editor's `{}` icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to me that "kali-linux-top10" is the [previous name of a metapackage](https://www.kali.org/blog/kali-linux-metapackages/) and that it is [now called](https://tools.kali.org/kali-metapackages) "kali-tools-top10". Similarly for "kali-linux-all" -- it now appears to be called "kali-linux-everything".

Comment: Perhaps there's a way to contact the maintainers of the web site.